# Searching a list of dataframes for a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I scraped a bunch of tables of financial data using pandas.read_excel.  I am trying to search through the list of dataframes and select only the ones that contain a certain value/string.  Is it possible to do that? I had thought I could do something like:

```
    search = [x.isin('string') for x in df_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want this (for each frame):

```
(df == 'foo').any()
```

That will return True if 'foo' is anywhere in the frame.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually went with this

`[x for x in list if True in (x == 'foo').any().unique()]`

Answer (score 0):

`[x for x in df.isin('string').any().sum()]`

check if word exist in each column and sum the boolean vales for each columns.

so, it will returm `True` if it exist at least in one of the columns.